# How to align image to the left when uses resizes Swiper js window?

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, swiper.js

Swiper is a carousel plugin. When a user resizes the window, the image gradually crops from both sides, which is great, but how do I make it to crop only from the right side while keeping the left side static?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-active" data-swiper-slide-index="0">

    <img src="img/double-room-1.jpg" 
    style="
        border-radius:10px; 
        width:100%; 
        height:100%;
        object-fit:cover;
        overflow:hidden;
    ">
    
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
.swiper-slide {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transition-property: transform;
}
```

Any suggestion would be largely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I did this by adding `updateOnWindowResize: false` to Swiper script.
So now it looks like this:

```
<script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        slidesPerView: 1,
        spaceBetween: 0,
        updateOnWindowResize: false, //This one is added
        loop: true,
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            clickable: true,
        },
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
    });
    </script>
```

Wee!